# Ribbon change the Headers text Color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ribbon

I am stuck with a little problem: The background Color of my Ribbon clashes badly with the default color of the RibbonGroups.
I am unable to change the color to something more readable, like plain black. I tried to set the TextBlock.Foreground Property and that changes the appearance in VS 2012, but not when the program is running.

The XAML is very straightforward:
I am using the stock Ribbon, no third party Controls.

```
            <RibbonTab x:Name="RTabPowerPoint" Header="Powerpoint">
                <RibbonGroup Header="Allgemeines">
                    <RibbonButton x:Name="cmdLoadPowerPoint" SmallImageSource="/Images/powerpoint-26.png" LargeImageSource="/Images/powerpoint-32.png" Label="Lade Datei"/>
                    <RibbonButton x:Name="CmdLoadBPZ" SmallImageSource="/Images/open_in_browser-26.png" LargeImageSource="/Images/open_in_browser-32.png" Label="Lade Vorlage"/>
                    <RibbonButton x:Name="cmdSaveOpenFiles" SmallImageSource="/Images/save-26.png" LargeImageSource="/Images/save-32.png" Label="Speichere Vorlage"/>
                    <RibbonButton x:Name="cmdChangeFiledestinationPowerPoint" SmallImageSource="/Images/sinchronize-26.png" LargeImageSource="/Images/sinchronize-32.png" Label="BLA"/>
                </RibbonGroup>
          </RibbonTab>
        </Ribbon>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change colour of `RibbonTab.Header` then you can use `TextBlock` instead and change its `Foreground`

```
<RibbonTab x:Name="RTabPowerPoint">
   <RibbonTab.Header>
      <TextBlock Text="Powerpoint" Foreground="Aqua"/>
   </RibbonTab.Header>

</RibbonTab>
```

Comment: Not as nice as "Header="bla", but it works! Thank you very much!